# Has anyone else seen the issue of Lightning Component, if updated to version 41.0, changes the Component Label by appending namespace

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error, bug, winter18, lightning-tab

```
No COMPONENT named markup://namespace:namespace_MyComponent found
```

This error pop up after I updated my Lightning Component to API version 41.0, and the error comes when the component has a dedicated Lightning Tab created for it.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

I'm noticing that Salesforce is changing the component Label to "namespace_ComponentName", i.e. appended the package's namespace as 
 "namespace_" to that component existing Label when it is updated to 41.0 API version.

This result in the old Lightning Tab not finding the component when loaded in end user org. As if, platform is locating the component by it's Label instead of Name.

**===== UPDATE =====**

I'm able to reproduce this at will, following these steps:

1. Arrange a Dev org and Add a Package Namespace to it.
2. Create or pick any Old version Lightning Component (and change the version to ANYTHING LESS THAN 40.0).
3. The Lightning Component must implement interface = "force:appHostable"
4. Create a Lightning Component Tab, and select the above created component in it.
5. Test and confirm that the Lightning Component Tab loads fine with your Test Component.
6. Change the Lightning Component Bundle API version to 41.0
7. Now load the Lightning Component Tab and you will see that error message in this format, as soon as you load the tab:
   "No COMPONENT named markup://namespace:namespace_TestComponent found"

where "namespace" is your package namespace of the organization.

> After updating Bundle API version to 41.0, even if you go back
>   to lower API version, this change will leave your Lightning Component
>   Tab, **unloadable** for users. So PLEASE be careful in trying the steps in your Live Production Components.